# How to automatically select a radio button?

Tags: civievent

For a civi event registration form, is there a way to select a radio button if one of 2 other fields has data? We want to require a security deposit if the person selects one of 2 other options on the form, but only if one of those 2 fields is selected/has data entered. Once it is selected, the user should not be able to deselect it, but the form should deselect the radio button if the user removes the options that caused the radio button to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

The [Profile Conditionals](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond) extension is intended to meet this need.  However, it doesn't have a user interface, so it requires some tech-savvy to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional filtering is not possible in CiviCRM but available on Drupal webform_civicrm. But not for complex scenario's like yours. However you can achieve what you want by writing a small extension and adding JS page on the form to perform selections and also you can use validateform civicrm hook to provide validation at server side.